# How to create multiple section using collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3

Method `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` does not exist.
Can we do that using collection view, or is it only possible through `TableView`?

Comment: delegate connected properly ?

Comment: Do you conform the UICollectionViewDataSource?

Comment: yes it is possible by using collection view. I presume you have not connected the collection view datasource and delegate properly.

Comment: Might Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102639/ios-8-swift-uicollectionview-multiple-sections-and-headers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 8 Swift UICollectionView Multiple Sections and Headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102639/ios-8-swift-uicollectionview-multiple-sections-and-headers)

Comment: And make sure to conform to **UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource**

Comment: @AhmadF it cannot be a duplicate of that question since it has no accepted answer

Comment: Yes i have used all ...but still number of sections method is not called. iOS 8 Swift UICollectionView Multiple Sections and Headers ...answer is not correct... .I guess we are not able to create mutiple section using collection view

Comment: @AhmadF you are right

Comment: @Xcoder123 accepted answer is not required, try to "flag" it :) the required condition is the flagged question must has answer(s).

Comment: @Xcoder123 i have already created headerView but it is called once since numberofSection has default 1 section

Comment: @GSiosdeveloper I hope that the "possible duplicated" question's answers are useful to your case. btw, if you found the exact answer in the duplicated question, I suggest to close this one ;)

Comment: @AhmadF its not duplicate at call ... i have tried that by creating header but its not working at all...u can also check that

Comment: Can you add the code you're trying to run?

Comment: Please explan more detailed and post code.

Comment: This method is available in swift 3.   `func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    }`

Comment: @RajeshkumarR  yes its available ....but its not get called at all....can you check that at your own end by putting breakpoint.

Comment: Tried with breakpoints. It worked.

Comment: Check these links. [pic1](http://prnt.sc/dtei0h) [pic2](http://prnt.sc/dtei54) [pic3](http://prnt.sc/dtei95) [pic4](http://prnt.sc/dteid3)