# How to display multiple sections in UICollectionView

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Collection view only shows the first section, but doesn't show the second section.

Here are the delegates

```
private func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var returnValue = Int()

    if section == 0 {
        returnValue = 1

    } else if section == 1 {
        returnValue = self.section1DataSource.count

    }

    return returnValue

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell = UICollectionViewCell()

    let cellA:GroupPhoto = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "groupPhotoCard", for: indexPath) as! GroupPhoto
    let cellB:AddFriendCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "addFriendCard", for: indexPath) as! AddFriendCell

    let section = indexPath.section

    if section == 0 {

        cell = cellA

    //end of section 0
    } else if section == 1 {
        cell = cellB
    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    var returnValue = CGSize()

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        returnValue = CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: collectionView.frame.size.height / 3.0 - 8)

    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        returnValue = CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width / 2.9 - 8, height: collectionView.frame.size.height / 2.9 - 8)
    }

    return returnValue
}
```

When I interchange the conditions so that the first section's cell will be assigned to the second section. It works fine, but it will still only show the first section and not the second.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102639/uicollectionview-multiple-sections-and-headers

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Signature of [`numberOfSections(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618023-numberofsections) is changed in Swift 3 it should be like this.

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int { 
    return 2 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In swift 3, **numberOfSectionsInCollectionView** is changed to **numberOfSections(in:)**

To avoid this, you should add **UICollectionViewDataSource**, to implement autocomplete.