# swift different number of cell in each section

Tags: swift

I'm trying to pull data from firebase and show it in a collectionView with sections. How can add a different number of cells per section as each firebase data node will not have the same number of posts.

```
var users = [User]()
var posts = [Post]()
```

Updated collection view methods:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! FollowingCell

    let user = self.users[indexPath.section]
    let post = self.dataSource[user]?[indexPath.row]
    cell.post = post

    return cell
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath) as! FollowingHeader

    let user = self.users[indexPath.section]
    header.user = user

    return header
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let user = self.users[section]
    return self.dataSource[user]?.count ?? 0
}


override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return self.dataSource.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 120, height: 80)
}
```

How I'm adding the posts and user. As you can see I'm adding the post to the dataSource but for some reason, only 1 post per use is added when one of the users has two posts.

```
func fetchFollowedEvents() {

    self.collectionView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

    guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("followed-posts").child(currentUid)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        dictionary.forEach { (key, value) in

            Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (postSnapshot) in

                guard let postDictionary = postSnapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
                guard let uid = postDictionary["uid"] as? String else { return }

                Database.fetchUserWithUID(uid: uid) { (user) in

                    let post = Post(postId: key, user: user, dictionary: postDictionary)
                    post.id = key


                    self.users.append(user)
                    self.dataSource[user] = [post]

                    self.collectionView.reloadData()

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try creating data source like this

```
var users : [User] = []()
var dataSource : [User:[Post]] = [:]() //I Prefer this one
(or)
var dataSource :[Int: [Post]] = [:]()
```

a dictionary with Users as Key and Array of post as Value
So now for number of sections you can use

```
   self.userser.count() 
   (or)
   self.dataSource.count()
```

So for number of rows in sections, you can do as so

```
   let user = self.users[section]
   return self.dataSource[user].count() ?? 0
   (or)
   return self.dataSource[section].count() ?? 0
```

in cell for row at index you can get the data as

```
let user = self.users[indexPath.section]
let data = self.dataSource[user][indexPath.row]
(or)
let data = self.dataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

Hope this would help you.
Happy Codding!

Comment: The only issue I'm having now is all the posts are falling under the same section header instead of corresponding user

Comment: I am not sure what is causing the issue, share your code ! and check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102639/uicollectionview-multiple-sections-and-headers. If it could help you.

Comment: I added how I'm adding the posts and user to the data source which I know is the issue because it's adding all the posts to the same user instead of the user which created the post

Comment: ok, bro, I think the issue is from where you add  data source. try 
              self.dataSource[user] = post 
instead of 
                    self.dataSource = [user: self.posts]. What you are doing is overriding the result with a new result. ending to store the last user's post in the datasource. so update that line as I said. So now you will add post to the data source to the unique key user. happy codding.

Comment: I think I'm very close to solving this thanks to you. I have one issue now though. My posts are not grouping. Only one post is returning per user. I have three posts being pulled from firebase, two belonging to one user but unfortunately, it's only showing one of the posts for the user with two posts. When I reload the collection view they switch between each other how can I display both under the right user? I've updated my code.

Comment: I have also updated the collectionView methods for you to look at. I appreciate it.

Comment: Only one post per user is being shown under each section when there are multiple posts per user, I updated my question with my code where it is occurring.

Comment: use break point and check what you are receiving
self.dataSource[user] = [post]
if you are receiving single post on the closue
you should do the following
var oldPosts = self.dataSource[user] ?? [String:Any]();
oldPosts.append(post);
self.dataSource[user] = oldPosts;

Comment: Thank you so much! The old posts solution is working perfectly.

Comment: happy to support !